# Comment pagination for D7?

Tags: 7, comments, paging

I am not able to see the comment pagination section, even though I set up the comment field under `structure/content-type/name/comment-field`. I set the limit of number of comments to display on node to 10. But when I have more than 10 comments on a node I still can't see the pagination bar at the bottom. Is there a module for custom pagination of comments?